# Need to make a shortcut command using xargs

Tags: bash, shortcuts

I always want to kill a process id which listening on Port 3000.
So presently I am using,

```
1.lsof -i tcp:3000
```

will give output as,

```
COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ruby    6697   xxxx   5u  IPv4 251982      0t0  TCP *:3000 (LISTEN)
```

and I will kill the PID using,
2. `kill -9 6697`

I want to create a bash program which do this process automatically.

I tried using xargs to get PID of the output of first command but failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you want the `-t` option to lsof, which only emits pids. You can give kill a list of pids too, so:

```
kill -9 $(lsof -ti tcp:3000)
```

If you do this a lot, make an alias

```
alias kill3000='kill -9 $(lsof -ti tcp:3000)'
```

Comment: :) with help of your command I created with xargs
alias kil='lsof -ti tcp:3000 | xargs kill -9'

Answer (score 1):

Here it is (without `xargs`):

```
lsof -i tcp:8080 | while read cmd pid rest; do ((pid)) && kill -9 $pid; done
```